# set.seed in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, random-seed, seed

I'm doing some analysis and I had to impute some values. To do so, I write this chunk of code:

A)

```
set.seed(1)
for (i in 2:length (Dataset[-c(8,11)])) { 
      Dataset[,i]<-impute(Dataset[,i], "random")
}
```

[[The -c(8,11) is for two characters columns]]

This does not give me any error so I'm not asking for this, but: is it correct to put `Set.seed(1)` outside the for loop?
Because the second time I ran this code the results (at the end of the analysis) were different.
So I put `Set.seed(1)` inside the for loop, like this:

B)

```
for (i in 2:length (Dataset[-c(8,11)])) { 
      set.seed(1)
      Dataset[,i]<-impute(Dataset[,i], "random")
}
```

This gave me a reproducible result, but if I put outside again the set.seed, now the result is stuck as in B (when it was inside the for loop).

So I'm quite confused: why does this happen? What is wrong with the syntax?
How can I effectively write a for loop with a `set.seed` to impute some values in the data set?

Comment: Do note that some of those columns being worked on will be the one you are apparently trying to avoid. (Also stop capitalizing `set.seed`.

Comment: Also what package does `impute` come from? There are several that have a function with this name.

Comment: @IRTFM Do you mean I should imputing only on the columns with missing?

Comment: @dcarlson it's from the Hmisc package, does it work differently?

Comment: Different packages are written by different people so you cannot assume functions with the same name will work the same. Without reproducible data, we cannot verify your issue. What is the difference between `Dataset` and `DatasetIMG_Methyl`. Code A uses both, Code B uses only DatasetIMG_Methyl. We don't have any information about either.

Comment: `Hmisc::impute` will not change vectors with no NAs so you don't need to avoid them. You had written  a llop over the values: `2:length (Dataset[-c(8,11)])`. If the length of Dataset were greater than 11, say 14, then that would sequence would have included both 8 and 11 which I was guessing was not your intent.. Since you had not described your intent for any of the lines of code it remains a wild ass guess.

Comment: @dcarlson my bad.. it was the same dataset, I just forgot to delete part of the name. I see I'll try to give you some reproducible data picking from my real dataset.

Comment: @IRTFM My idea was only to impute some missing in a dataset of 90 rows and 150 columns ( about 30 spots inside the dataset)... Columns 8 and 11 are strings by the way

Comment: I thought that was your idea, and I was trying to advise against that code because it would not do what you hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code does not do what you think it is doing. The problem is

```
for (i in 2:length(Dataset[-c(8,11)]))
```

You are not removing the columns from the loop, only from the length of the data frame. If the data frame has 20 columns, you will run the loop from column 2 to column 18 because you have just reduced the number of columns. Instead you should use `i in 2:length(Dataset)[-c(8, 11)]`. Since `impute` will jump over these columns if the are character data, you don't need to exclude them from the loop.

Second, we can test your question about the reproducibility of the results when the seed appears outside the loop. Here is a small example using the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
data(iris)
set.seed(42)
Data <- iris[1:25, -5]
idx <- matrix(replicate(4, sample.int(25, 5)), 20)
idx <- cbind(idx, rep(1:4, each=5))
Data[idx] <- NA
head(Data)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3          NA
# 4           NA          NA          1.5          NA
# 5           NA         3.6           NA          NA
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Now we impute the missing values three times:

```
library(Hmisc)
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:4) {
    Data[, i] <- impute(Data[, i], "random")
}
Data[idx]
#  [1] 5.8 4.9 4.6 4.7 5.4 3.4 3.5 3.3 3.6 3.8 1.3 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.3
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:4) {
    Data[, i] <- impute(Data[, i], "random")
}
Data[idx]
#  [1] 5.8 4.9 4.6 4.7 5.4 3.4 3.5 3.3 3.6 3.8 1.3 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.3
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:4) {
    Data[, i] <- impute(Data[, i], "random")
}
Data[idx]
#  [1] 5.8 4.9 4.6 4.7 5.4 3.4 3.5 3.3 3.6 3.8 1.3 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.3
```

The imputed values are the same each time.